# Echad Vachamishim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred fifty-one?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting and relevant answers.*
- *Accept the what I think is the "best" answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

*Back to hard ones, a prime in this case.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There were](http://web.archive.org/web/20070816193605/www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/torah_timeline.html) 251 years from *Avraham*'s birth to *Yosef*'s.

Answer (score 4):

The coming Shavuos (first day outside Eretz Yisrael, only day in it) marks 251 years since the passing of the Baal Shem Tov (in the year 5520/1760).

Answer (score 1):

From 1805 to 1855 (which are apparently the years for which records are available), the London *bes din* converted 251 minors who had Jewish fathers. ([Source.](http://books.google.com/books?id=u7d8QkOggvQC&pg=PA159&dq=fifty))